# Users restrictions for associated data in ASP Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a site I'm porting to MVC to clean up the code and simplify things.  I use the asp membership and profile providers, but I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly for my situtation.  I'm pretty new to MVC, so I wan to get this right in the early stages.

Users are individuals and they are part of larger "institutions" that they either set up or pick at registration.  In this case, the institution is a winery.  I want the users to be able to view all wines from every winery, but only edit ones that belong to them.

What's the best way to do this?  Right now I render the link to the edit field in my index view based on their instution ID and the producer ID.  I feel like a data annotation might work better here, but I don't exactly how to implement that for a group of wines.  Do I need multiple providers?  I use roles to limit the editing, but right now an editor role could manually enter the path of another wine to edit it when that wine doesn't belong to them.

Any pointers here would be awesome.  I know I can do it in the controller methods, but I'm looking for the 'right' way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into the same issue at work right now, and the best proposed solution we have right now is implementing an "ownership" table. You won't be able to solve this using roles.

So basically you have an owner ID, owned object's ID, and the type of objects ID all held together. Lets take an edit request for example. We know that you can only edit the data person X owns, so we have a stored procedure that if a key combination exists in our ownership table where person.ID = owner ID, and item.ID = object ID, and item.TypeID = objectTypeID. If it exists, it goes along performing its edits, otherwise it returns an error.

You can use this scheme to return ownership lists, user validation, and a host of other issues you may come across. You probably won't need the ObjectTypeID if you only have one type's ownership being tracked. Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually figured this out with a custom AuthorizeAttribute.  I'll post it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by applying a custom AuthorizeAttribute to the edit, delete, and create actions.

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    public class ProducerEditAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private vfContext db = new vfContext();

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        bool bAdmin = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("admin");
        bool bProdEdit = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("producereditor");
        bool bProd = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("producer");

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (bAdmin)
            {
                //authorized
            }

            if (bProdEdit || bProd)
            {
                //check for current wine belonging to the producer.  
                Producer currentProd = db.Producers.Find(Profile.GetProfile(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).InstitutionID);
                Wine currentWine;
                object WineID;
                if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("id", out WineID))
                {
                    currentWine = db.Wines.Find(int.Parse(WineID.ToString()));
                    if (currentProd.Wines.Contains(currentWine) && bProdEdit)
                    {
                        //authorized
                    }
                    else if (bProd)
                    {
                        var result = new ViewResult();
                        result.ViewName = "Login.cshtml";        //this can be a property you don't have to hard code it
                        result.MasterName = "_Layout.cshtml";    //this can also be a property
                        result.ViewBag.Message = "You do not have permission for add/edit/delete funciontionality.  Please request.";
                        filterContext.Result = result;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = new ViewResult();
                        result.ViewName = "Login.cshtml";
                        result.MasterName = "_Layout.cshtml"; 
                        filterContext.Result = result;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = new ViewResult();
                result.ViewName = "Login.cshtml";
                result.MasterName = "_Layout.cshtml";   
            }


        }
    }
}
```